# python tkinter cursor icon change size

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, cursor

[enter image description here][1]I want to change the mouse icon on Tkinter to the resizing icon(when you take the mouse to the edges of a window it appears). I know I should use `root.configure(cursor="the name")` but I don't know the name and I searched it in the internet bot a long list came up and none of them was what I want.
please just tell me the name of this icon.

[this icon and horizontal and vertical type of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY5e1.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this resource](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/cursors.html), you should use `widget.configure(cursor="sb_h_double_arrow")`. Here is the full list:

```
arrow
man
middlebutton
mouse
pencil
pirate
plus
question_arrow
right_ptr
right_side
right_tee
rightbutton
rtl_logo
sailboat
sb_down_arrow
sb_h_double_arrow
sb_left_arrow
sb_right_arrow
sb_up_arrow
sb_v_double_arrow
shuttle
sizing
spider
spraycan
star
target
tcross
top_left_arrow
top_left_corner
top_right_corner
top_side
top_tee
trek
ul_angle
umbrella
ur_angle
watch
xterm
X_cursor
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: thanks but I don't want that icon i edited my question and there is pictures of what i want

Comment: `sb_h_double_arrow`?